# sm.density.compare() plot not showing anything

Tags: r, density-plot

I'm using `sm.density.compare()` function to visualize if my variable of interest helps distinguish categorical outcome variable (a variable of 13 classes) using the following code:

```html
library(sm)
load("~/df.Rdata")
sm.density.compare(df$X, df$Y, col=rainbow(13))
```

But as it turned out, this density plot doesn't show anything. Did I omit some code in `sm.density.compare()` or simply because the `X` is uninformative?

[image]

FYI, the data can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7i9e75xd62yi9b/df.Rdata?dl=0) and I referenced this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310889/poor-multiclass-classification-using-caret-in-r) from another forum.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, only two points have df$Y ==2 and both have the same X value, so there is no good way to define the density for those points. If you leave out the Y==2 points,  the plot works fine.

```
SUB = which(df$Y != 2)
sm.density.compare(df$X[SUB], df$Y[SUB])
```

[image: Density plot]

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me identify the problem with the data.